# Processing: createShape returns null when called inside setup from eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, processing

I am migrating a working processing code into an Eclipse project because I want to use some android features which aren't easily available from PDE. Now I keep getting this nasty error:

```
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768): FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768): Process: com.pbtgames.defuser, PID: 19768
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void processing.core.PShape.setFill(int)' on a null object reference
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768):    at com.pbtgames.defuser.Main$Cell.recomputeShape(Main.java:467)
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768):    at com.pbtgames.defuser.Main$Cell.changeComplexity(Main.java:460)
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768):    at com.pbtgames.defuser.Main$Cell.<init>(Main.java:446)
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768):    at com.pbtgames.defuser.Main$Board.initGrid(Main.java:690)
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768):    at com.pbtgames.defuser.Main$Board.<init>(Main.java:648)
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768):    at com.pbtgames.defuser.Main.setup(Main.java:85)
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768):    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768):    at processing.core.PGraphicsAndroid2D.requestDraw(Unknown Source)
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768):    at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
02-20 21:51:01.852: E/AndroidRuntime(19768):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The stack trace is simple, inside setup, I'm initializing a Board class:

```
board = new Board(boardWidth);
```

Which in turn initializes a List of Cells. for every Cell I have a `PShape` property called "form" which is not initialized by default:

```
PShape form;
```

Inside Cell's constructor, I initialize it like this:

```
form = createShape();
form.setFill(c);
form.beginShape();
form.noStroke();
PVector[] pts = polygon(0, 0, r, complexity, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++)
    form.vertex(pts[i].x, pts[i].y);
form.endShape(CLOSE);
```

But my code crashes when it reaches:

```
form.setFill(c);
```

This exact code works perfectly when started from PDE. any ideas?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I realized the real problem was I was using the `size` method to define `P2D` renderer and that is not available in android mode. Instead I had to add this piece of code:

```
public String sketchRenderer() {
    return P2D; 
}
```

This fixed the issue with `createShape` method. but I still faced a few other bugs regarding my use of other libraries inside the code. I could solve them one by one but I trust that PDE does all the necessary changes when it generates an android project. So I'm gonna stick with the solution of modifying the auto generated android project.

Comment: Let's see your *createShape()* code, as that's where the bug is.

Comment: @gknicker createShape() is not my code. it's one of the methods accessible from processing.core.PApplet and my code is running in a class which extends PApplet.

Comment: I see. In that case I have two suspicions. The first is, if you've simulated an Android environment, whether there is even applet support. The second suspicion is that you're calling instance methods from constructors, which is not recommended in Java - I'd recommend you restructure your code to remove the instance method calls from constructors and constructor chaining from Board to Cell.

Comment: @gknicker In order to port the code to eclipse, I used the guidelines from http://blog.onthewings.net/2013/04/25/setting-up-a-processing-android-project-in-eclipse/
Also, I'm quite certain it's not a problem caused by chaining constructors. I regenerated the same error with a much lighter code. problem is with calling createShape inside setup. I'm thinking createShape is using a Graphics object which isn't accessible from an Activity's onCreate (PApplet extends android Activity not java Applet). but then again, I don't know where else to do this sort of initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this question [PShape 2.08 throws NullPointerException with createShape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601675/pshape-2-08-throws-nullpointerexception-with-createshape) and used PGraphics instead of PShape as suggested. For now it works, but I'm gonna see if I can port all my shapes to PGraphics objects before accepting this as a solution.

UPDATE:

I ported my shapes to PGraphics but the rendering performance is significantly decreased! I'm wondering what PDE does before generating my apk. This solution is basically useless for me.

SOLUTION:

I found the temporary project PDE generates in C:\Users\Mohsen\AppData\Local\Temp\android8159256509115545375sketch
(the exact location is printed in console when PDE is compiling the android code)
Now I can import this project into eclipse and make my modifications there instead of porting everything by building an android project from the scratch.